# How to create a mesh of objects circling a sphere

Tags: modifiers

I'm making an animation. Two planets - one in the center, the other one - smaller - orbiting it.

The large one needs to have satellites orbiting it, and these satellites need to be facing the small planet.
[image: preview from blender]

The network of satellites needs to be ordered in a sort of a mesh, let's say like that, in a kind of a plus-formation:

[image]

Would you be able to recommend a modifier?

Comment: yes! geometry nodes modifier!

Comment: @Chris Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the distribution of the satellites, I have used a cylinder with 2 side segments.
(Increase the vertex count to have more satellites) Took the same cylinder and rotated it by 90deg to have the plus you are looking for.

Now on these cylinders I have instanced the satellite object.

To align these instances to the other planet, we have to set the rotation value in the instance on points node in a particular way.

By subtracting the position of the instances from the location of the other planet, we get a vector pointing from the instance to the planet.
Now, using the Align Euler to Vector node we can use this created vector to align the satellites pointing towards the other planet.

(To animate the satellites around the planet just use a transform node right before the instance on points node and animate the rotation as you like)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a cool one @Akhay2005! I managed to work my way out of this by implementing a method from this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a77tS9bukvU

@Chris Thanks for the tip!